# Form Not Sending any Inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a request form for the user. The two problems I'm facing are

1. Whatever the sender fills the form or any input and sends it, the receiver does see it.
2. the form has multi-select option like if you choose an option show that and hide other options but when the user fills the inputs from one option the remaining blank input field also shows that.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#select-2 option:not([default])').wrap('<span/>');
});

$('#select-1').change(function() {
  $('#select-2 span > option').unwrap();
  $('#select-2 option:not(.' + $('#select-1').val() + ', [default])').wrap('<span/>');
  //console.log($('#select-2').val());
});

$('#select-2').trigger('change');
$("#otherFieldGroupMod").hide();
$("#otherFieldGroupRes").hide();
$("#otherFieldGroupRem").hide();
$("#otherFieldGroupOutacc").hide();
$("#outlookAccountDistri").hide();
$("#otherFieldGroupWinacc").hide();
$("#otherFieldGroupKdrive").hide();
$("#otherFieldGroupDcnet").hide();
$("#otherFieldGroupResPass").hide();
$("#otherFieldGroupValpo").hide();

//AS400 NEW ACCOUNT SCRIPT//
$(function() {
  $("#select-2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "option-1a") {
      $("#otherFieldGroupNewacc").show();
    } else {
      $("#otherFieldGroupNewacc").hide();
    }
  });
});

//AS400 MODFIY ACCOUNT SCRIPT//
$(function() {
  $("#select-2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "option-1b") {
      $("#otherFieldGroupMod").show();
    } else {
      $("#otherFieldGroupMod").hide();
    }
  });
});

//AS400 RESET ACCOUNT SCRIPT//
$(function() {
  $("#select-2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "option-1c") {
      $("#otherFieldGroupRes").show();
    } else {
      $("#otherFieldGroupRes").hide();
    }
  });
});

//OUTLOOK NEW ACCOUNT /
$(function() {
  $("#select-2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "option-2a") {
      $("#otherFieldGroupOutacc").show();
    } else {
      $("#otherFieldGroupOutacc").hide();
    }
  });
});

//Add TO DISTRIBUTION LIST
$(function() {
  $("#select-2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "option-2b") {
      $("#outlookAccountDistri").show();
    } else {
      $("#outlookAccountDistri").hide();
    }
  });
});

//WINDOWS NEW ACCOUNT SCRIPT//
$(function() {
  $("#select-2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "option-3a") {
      $("#otherFieldGroupWinacc").show();
    } else {
      $("#otherFieldGroupWinacc").hide();
    }
  });
});

//K DRIVE AND GROUP ACCESS
$(function() {
  $("#select-2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "option-3b") {
      $("#otherFieldGroupKdrive").show();
    } else {
      $("#otherFieldGroupKdrive").hide();
    }
  });
});

//DC NET ACCESS
$(function() {
  $("#select-2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "option-3c") {
      $("#otherFieldGroupDcnet").show();
    } else {
      $("#otherFieldGroupDcnet").hide();
    }
  });
});

//RESET PASSWORD ACCESS
$(function() {
  $("#select-2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "option-3d") {
      $("#otherFieldGroupResPass").show();
    } else {
      $("#otherFieldGroupResPass").hide();
    }
  });
});

//VAPLO NEW ACCOUNT SCRIPT//
$(function() {
  $("#select-2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "option-4a") {
      $("#otherFieldGroupValpo").show();
    } else {
      $("#otherFieldGroupValpo").hide();
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
    $('#select-4 option:not([default])').wrap('<span/>');
});

$('#select-3').change(function() {
    $('#select-4 span > option').unwrap();
    $('#select-4 option:not(.' + $('#select-3').val() + ', [default])').wrap('<span/>');
    //console.log($('#select-2').val());
});

$('#select-4').trigger('change');
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body,
div,
form,
input,
label {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 18px;
}

legend {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #095484;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

.testbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 20px;
}

form {
  width: 75%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 #095484;
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("/Krishneel/Walgreens Logo's/Walgreens New Logo/banner.png");
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.banner::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  padding: 5px;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="testbox">
  <form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="banner">
      <h1>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;ID Request Form</h1>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p>Please fill out with the information that is requested below and submit the id request form. Thank you!</p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Request Type</label>
      <select id="select-1" name="select-1" class="form-control w-100">
        <option default>Choose a Category</option>
        <option value="option-1">AS400</option>
        <option value="option-2">Outlook</option>
        <option value="option-3">Windows</option>
        <option value="option-4">Valpo</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      <label>Choose a Sub-Category</label>
      <select id="select-2" name="select-2" class="form-control w-100">
        <option default>Choose a Sub-Category</option>
        <option value="option-1a" class="option-1">AS400 New Account</option>
        <option value="option-1b" class="option-1">Modify Account</option>
        <option value="option-1c" class="option-1">Reset Password</option>
        <option value="option-1d" class="option-1">Remove Password</option>
        <option value="option-2a" class="option-2">Outlook New Account</option>
        <option value="option-2b" class="option-2">Add to Distribution List</option>
        <option value="option-3a" class="option-3">Windows New Account</option>
        <option value="option-3b" class="option-3">K Drive and Group Access</option>
        <option value="option-3c" class="option-3">DC Net</option>
        <option value="option-3d" class="option-3">Password Reset</option>
        <option value="option-4a" class="option-4">Valpo New Account</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <!----------------------------------------------------- AS400 Account------------------------------------------->
    <!--AS400 New Account-->
    <div class="form-group" id="otherFieldGroupNewacc">
      <h2>AS400 New Account</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userRequestor">Requestor Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userRequestor" name="userRequestor" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userTM">Beneficiary (Full Name)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userTM" name="userTM" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userEmployee">Employee ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userEmployee" name="userEmployee" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="selectJob">New Job Category</label>
          <select id="selectJob" name="selectJob" class="form-control w-100" placeholder="*Click in box for Job Category List*">
            <option value="NO CHANGE">NO CHANGE</option>
            <option value="ADMCLK = Admin Clerk">ADMCLK = Admin Clerk</option>
            <option value="ADMCLK+ = Admin Clerk w/ Manual Book">ADMCLK+ = Admin Clerk w/ Manual Book</option>
            <option value="ADMMGR = Admin MGR w/ Manual Book">ADMMGR = Admin MGR w/ Manual Book</option>
            <option value="DCM = DC Manager">DCM = DC Manager</option>
            <option value="FM IN = Inbound Funtion Manager">FM IN = Inbound Funtion Manager</option>
            <option value="FM OUT = Outbound Funtion Manager">FM OUT = Outbound Funtion Manager</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userNewAS400">New AS400 ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userNewAS400" name="userNewAS400" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modify AS400 Account-->
    <div class="form-group" id="otherFieldGroupMod">
      <h2>AS400 Modify Account</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userRequestor">Requester (Full Name)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userRequestor" name="userRequestor" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userTM">Beneficiary (Full Name)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userTM" NAME="userTM" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userEmployee">Employee ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userEmployee" name="userEmployee" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userAS400">AS400 ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userAS400" name="userAS400" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="selectJobs">New Job Category></label>
          <select id="selectJobs" name="selectJobs" class="form-control w-100" placeholder="*Click in box for Job Category List*">
            <option value="NO CHANGE">NO CHANGE</option>
            <option value="ADMCLK = Admin Clerk">ADMCLK = Admin Clerk</option>
            <option value="ADMCLK+ = Admin Clerk w/ Manual Book">ADMCLK+ = Admin Clerk w/ Manual Book</option>
            <option value="ADMMGR = Admin MGR w/ Manual Book">ADMMGR = Admin MGR w/ Manual Book</option>
            <option value="DCM = DC Manager">DCM = DC Manager</option>
            <option value="FM IN = Inbound Funtion Manager">FM IN = Inbound Funtion Manager</option>
            <option value="FM OUT = Outbound Funtion Manager">FM OUT = Outbound Funtion Manager</option>
            <option value="FM LC = Location Control Function Manager">FM LC = Location Control Function Manager</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userNewAS400">New AS400 ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userNewAS400" name="userNewAS400" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Reinstate AS400 Account-->
    <div class="form-group" id="otherFieldGroupRes">
      <h2>AS400 Reinstate Password</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userRequestor">Requester (Full Name)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userRequestor" name="userRequestor" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userTM">Beneficiary (Full Name)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userTM" NAME="userTM" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userEmployee">Employee ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userEmployee" name="userEmployee" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userAS400">AS400 ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userAS400" name="userAS400" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Remove AS400 Account-->
    <div class="form-group" id="otherFieldGroupRem">
      <h2>Remove AS400 Account</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userRequestor">Requester (Full Name)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userRequestor" name="userRequestor" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userTM">Terminated TM (Full Name)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userTM" NAME="userTM" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userEmployee">Employee ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userEmployee" name="userEmployee" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userAS400">AS400 ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userAS400" name="userAS400" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="hideInput">Reason</label>
          <input type="text" id="hideInput" value="No Longer With The Company!">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!---Outlook Account---->
    <!--New Account-->
    <div class="form-group" id="otherFieldGroupOutacc">
      <h2>Outlook New Account</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userRequestor">Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userRequestor" name="userRequestor" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userEmployee">Employee ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userEmployee" name="userEmployee" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="useroneID">ONE ID (Formally Authenticator ID)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="useroneID" name="useroneID" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Add to Distribution List-->
    <div class="form-group" id="outlookAccountDistri">
      <h2>Add to Distribution List</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userRequestor">Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userRequestor" name="userRequestor" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="useroneID">ONE ID (Formally Authenticator ID)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="useroneID" name="useroneID" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="select-5">Select a Distribution List</label>
          <select id="select-5" name="select-5" class="form-control w-100" placeholder="*Click in box for Distribution List*">
            <option default>Choose a Distribution List</option>
            <option value="WoodlandDInsuffAitems">WoodlandDInsuffAitems</option>
            <option value="WoodlandOutboundManagers">WoodlandOutboundManagers</option>
            <option value="WoodlandSrManagers">WoodlandSrManagers</option>
            <option value="WoodlandExpiredItems">WoodlandExpiredItems</option>
            <option value="WoodlandFleetManagers">WoodlandFleetManagers</option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Windows New Account-->
    <div class="form-group" id="otherFieldGroupWinacc">
      <h2>Windows New Account</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userRequestor">Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userRequestor" name="userRequestor" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userEmployee">Employee ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userEmployee" name="userEmployee" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="useroneID">ONE ID (Formally Authenticator ID)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="useroneID" name="useroneID" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userMirror"> Mirror Account ONE ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userMirror" name="userMirror" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userComment">Comments</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userComment" name="userComment" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--K Drive and Group Access-->
    <div class="form-group" id="otherFieldGroupKdrive">
      <h2>K Drive and Group Access</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userRequestor">Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userRequestor" name="userRequestor" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userEmployee">Employee ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userEmployee" name="userEmployee" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="useroneID">ONE ID (Formally Authenticator ID)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="useroneID" name="useroneID" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userMirror"> Mirror Account ONE ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userMirror" name="userMirror" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userComment">Comments</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userComment" name="userComment" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--DC Net Access-->
    <div class="form-group" id="otherFieldGroupDcnet">
      <h2>DC Net Access</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userRequestor">Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userRequestor" name="userRequestor" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userEmployee">Employee ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userEmployee" name="userEmployee" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="useroneID">ONE ID (Formally Authenticator ID)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="useroneID" name="useroneID" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label> Select your Job Title</label>
          <select id="select-3" name="select-3" class="form-control w-100">
            <option default>Select an option</option>
            <option value="option-1">TM</option>
            <option value="option-2">DCS</option>
            <option value="option-3">AP Officer</option>
            <option value="option-4">IO</option>
            <option value="option-5">AGM</option>
            <option value="option-6">GM</option>
            <option value="option-7">IT Support</option>
          </select>
          <br><br>
          <select id="select-4" name="select-4" class="form-control w-100">
            <option default>Select your Department & Shift</option>
            <option value="option-1a" class="option-1">Cost Recovery</option>
            <option value="option-1b" class="option-1">Lean Captain</option>
            <option value="option-2a" class="option-2">SC-AM</option>
            <option value="option-2b" class="option-2">SC-PM</option>
            <option value="option-2c" class="option-2">FC-AM</option>
            <option value="option-2d" class="option-2">FC-PM</option>
            <option value="option-2e" class="option-2">INB-AM</option>
            <option value="option-2f" class="option-2">INB-PM</option>
            <option value="option-2g" class="option-2">Shipping-AM</option>
            <option value="option-2h" class="option-2">Shipping-PM</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Password Access-->
    <div class="form-group" id="otherFieldGroupResPass">
      <h2>Reset Windows Password</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="col-6">
        <label for="otherField11">Click the link for Reset Password Help</label>
        <a href="http://wddc.walgreens.com/Forms/Password Resets & Account Unlocks for Direct Reports.pdf">Password Resets & Account Unlocks for Direct Reports</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--New Account-->
    <div class="form-group" id="otherFieldGroupValpo">
      <h2>Valpo New Account</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userRequestor">Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userRequestor" name="userRequestor" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userEmployee">Employee ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userEmployee" name="userEmployee" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="useroneID">ONE ID (Formally Authenticator ID)</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="useroneID" name="useroneID" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userBadge">Badge Number</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userBadge" name="userBadge" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Sending Email-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userEmail">Enter your Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userEmail" name="userEmail" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="send" class="btn-submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Put all your code inside `$(function() {...})`

Comment: Why do you have a separate `.change()` call for each value? Just write one handler, and put all the `if` statements in it.

Comment: Your sentence was cut off: "when the user fills" -- what?

Comment: You have a syntax error here: `select - 4 option: not([`. This should be the selector in `$("...")`. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: fixed the third and fourth comment

Comment: the first and send i try do it but the code wont do nothing unless i miss a line of code. Can you help me fix it

Comment: I submitted the form and the Network tab of Developer Tools showed that the form fields were sent. Do you see something different in your console?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the second problem. When I change options from the menus, I get blank fields, except for the `Email` field at the end.

Comment: yes the form does send but on my side when I fill the data or write anything in the  inputs and submit the form the receiver doesn't see anything except for select choices

Comment: The problem is that you have the same names of the inputs in different sections of the form. All of them are sent to the server, and it uses the value from the last one. You should give them different names.

Comment: for this" I'm not sure what you mean by the second problem. When I change options from the menus, I get blank fields, except for the Email field at the end" -- I mean if i select the as400 and then as00 new 400 and fill the inputbox and submit the form and when i see it it also  displays the inputs as blank from all other select options

Comment: also if you fill the form do you see data based on what you filled

Comment: See my earlier comment. I see what I filled and also empty values with the same field name. The controller will use the last one.

Comment: ok i will change the names of each input

Comment: can you show an example from my code